# how to retrieve multiple cart item values from response array paypal

Tags: php, paypal, foreach, paypal-sandbox

I am using the classic API and can do most things however I have encountered a problem I cannot seem to get around. I am using PHP and after I get a successful "ACK" from GetExpressCheckoutDetails I try to loop through the response array to get multiple items but it will not accept my code. 
I can var_dump the response array and it clearly shows the keys and values and I can test output of the values and it looks like this

```
Item Name = L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0

Item Name = 45065

Item Name = L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1

Item Name = 16030
```

My for loop looks like this
where "$httpParsedResponseAr" is the response array from PayPal

```
$index = 0;
foreach ($httpParsedResponseAr as $key => $value){                  
    if ($key == 'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME{$index}'){
      echo '<tr> ';
      echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#39AD43"> 
              <p>Item Name = '.$key.'</p>
              <p>Item Name = '.$value.'</p>
            </td>';
     echo '</tr>';'
     } 
     $index++;
}
```

the above returns nothing however,

It will let me "hard-code" the key string like below and return the correct value

```
$index = 0;
foreach ($httpParsedResponseAr as $key => $value){                  
    if ($key == 'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0'){
      echo '<tr> ';
      echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#39AD43"> 
              <p>Item Name = '.$key.'</p>
              <p>Item Name = '.$value.'</p>
            </td>';
     echo '</tr>';'
     } 
     $index++;
}
```

My problem is that I will not know how many items are included in the response (added to buyers cart) so do not know how many index numbers to use so that is why the foreach loop.

I have tried this also

```
        if ($key == 'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME'.$index){
```

How do I retrieve these multiple values?

I have tried all different combinations for the string but they are not working. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` incremental operator is misplaced and I have replaced `'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME{$index}'` with `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME$index`
or you can also use `"L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME{$index}"`.

**Try this which worked for me:**

```
$index = 0;
foreach ($httpParsedResponseAr as $key => $value){                  
    if ($key == "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME$index"){
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#39AD43"> 
              <p>Item Name = '.$key.'</p>
              <p>Item Value= '.$value.'</p>
            </td>';
      echo '</tr>';
      $index++;
     } 
}
```

This is what I passed in SETEC:

```
  . "&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout" 
       . "&VERSION=115.0" 
       . "&RETURNURL=http://localhost/justbuy/ec_check.php"
       . "&CANCELURL=http://localhost/justbuy/ec_check.php"
       . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD"
       . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=99.30"
       . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=2.58"
       // . "&localecode=zh_HK"
       . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=101.88"
       . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD"
       . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale"
       . "&SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole"

       . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=1 Decaf Kona Blend Coffee  "
       . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=623083"
       . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1"
       . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=9.95 "
       . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=2"

        . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=Coffee Filter bags  "
       . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1=623084"
       . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=1"
       . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=39.70"
       . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=2";
```

and the response when I print the GETEC response:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response however, when I tried the code it only updated the key name with index number ("L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1","L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME2" etc) but the values returned were all the same for each of the new key names. I shall keep trying.

Comment: To clarify further. Your code does increment the name correctly but the values returned are the value of the first index for all names for example; 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0 = ted
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1 = ted
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME2 = ted
etc
What i need is;
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0 = ted
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0 = jim
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0 = mary
etc
cheers

Comment: Thanks techycommerce that worked well! I appreciate the time you put into this.